# Vanilla JS - Looping through a list and inserting an element causes infinite loop error

Tags: javascript

I have a nav menu and want to add a decorative element between each item. Outside of the loop my code seems to work when I target a specific list item with [0], but when used inside the loop using [i] the page never finishes loading.

When i move to JSbin to test, I am getting infinite loop errors.

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu-mobile-navigation">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Etc</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var mobileNav = document.getElementById('menu-mobile-navigation');
var mobileNavChildren = mobileNav.children;

// var decoration = document.createElement('div');
// decoration.classList.add( 'decoration' );
// mobileNav.insertBefore( decoration, mobileNavChildren[0].nextSibling ); // works outside loop


for (var i = 0; i < mobileNavChildren.length; i++) {

  var decoration = document.createElement('div');
  decoration.classList.add( 'decoration' );
  mobileNav.insertBefore( decoration, mobileNavChildren[i].nextSibling ); // page never loads, infinite loop error in JSbin

}
```

Comment: [`.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) returns a live `HTMLCollection`. Everytime you add a new element to `mobileNav` the elements in `mobileNavChildren` will be "updated" with that new element too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.children` of an element returns a *live* HTMLCollectio, which will mutate *even as you iterate over it* if elements get added to it in the middle of looping:

```js
var mobileNav = document.getElementById('menu-mobile-navigation');
var mobileNavChildren = mobileNav.children;
console.log(mobileNavChildren.length);
mobileNav.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
console.log(mobileNavChildren.length);
```

```html
<ul id="menu-mobile-navigation">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Etc</li>
</ul>
```

You want a static collection instead - consider using `querySelectorAll`, or spreading into an array:

```js
const mobileNav = document.getElementById('menu-mobile-navigation');
const mobileNavChildren = mobileNav.querySelectorAll('li');

for (var i = 0; i < mobileNavChildren.length; i++) {
  var decoration = document.createElement('div');
  decoration.classList.add( 'decoration' );
  mobileNav.insertBefore( decoration, mobileNavChildren[i].nextSibling );

}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-mobile-navigation">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Etc</li>
</ul>
```

Though, also note that a `<div>` should *not* be a child of a `<ul>` - only list elements should be children of a `<ul>`.

Comment: Alternatively you can put `mobileNavChildren` in an array: `const arr = [ ...mobileNavChildren ]`

Comment: Or reverse the loop: `for (var i = mobileNavChildren.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help on this. I went for changing the HTMLCollection to an array, but reversing the loop also worked.